# windows symbolic link target

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

Say that I setup a symbolic link:

```
 mklink  /D C:\root\Public\mytextfile.txt C:\root\Public\myothertextfile.txt
```

is there a way to see what the target of myothertextfile.txt is using the command line?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you please be more descriptive?

Answer (score 3):

```
C:\root\public>mklink   C:\root\Public\mytextfile.txt C:\root\Public\myothertextfile.txt
symbolic link created for C:\root\Public\mytextfile.txt <<===>> C:\root\Public\myothertextfile.txt

C:\root\public>dir

 Directory of C:\root\public

04/17/2012  05:42 PM    <DIR>          .
04/17/2012  05:42 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/17/2012  05:38 PM                 0 myothertextfile.txt
04/17/2012  05:42 PM    <SYMLINK>      mytextfile.txt [C:\root\Public\myothertextfile.txt]
```